# Electrical - Low beams out, high beams still work

Tags: electrical, lights, mitsubishi, lancer

I have a 2001 Mitsubishi Lancer CE, unfortunately both low beam headlights don't work. However, high beams and parking lights both work. I've checked the fuse, relay and bulb, all appear to be working. You can also hear the relay clicking when the low beam is turned on, so I don't believe it's the stalk switch.

For reference on the 3 terminals to the headlights I get +12V on all terminals while low beam is on, and one terminal drops to 0V while high beam is on.

I've run out of ideas on what to test, any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
I believe it is indeed the switch, as the high beam toggle no longer works, it will only stay on while it is held on. Also after turning the high beam on and off repeatedly the low beam now works again :D, and of course turning the high beam on again may stop the low beam from working again :(. So looks like I'll be heading to the wreckers for a new switch.

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

@resident_heretic

I'm pretty sure my Lancer uses H4 bulbs, I can see the two filaments within the bulb. Regardless I tested the bulb on another vehicle and it worked fine, both high and low beam.

I believe it is indeed the switch, as the high beam toggle no longer works, it will only stay on while it is held on. Also after turning the high beam on and off repeatedly the low beam now works again :D, and of course turning the high beam on again may stop the low beam from working again :(. So looks like I'll be heading to the wreckers for a new switch.

Comment: There you go...must have be a different model :)  Good luck at the wreckers.....

Answer (score 1):

When you say power to all terminals, do you mean all three? You need a ground connection to complete the circuit so the light will turn on. You should have two filaments in each bulb. Both filaments should share a ground connection and have a connection for high and one for low.  You should have power to one when on low and the other on high, then ground on the last.

Comment: Yes I get +12Volts on all 3 terminals to the headlight, and without a voltage drop no current can flow. From what I've gathered from google, turning the low beams on should set one of the terminals to 0V aka ground and thus allow current to flow, however it doesn't. High beam does turn one of the terminals to 0V.

Comment: I am not familiar with that car, but I would suspect the switch as the problem, unless there has been other wiring issues or repairs.

Answer (score 0):

The lancer's headlights are H11 type bulbs which are single filament. Perhaps the bulb is merely burnt out. Since low beams usually get more use than high beams they tend to burn out first.